# cant install pip package

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I am trying to make my own python3 pip package. I uploaded it online with twine from my command line, and I can see it online here:

https://pypi.org/project/example-pkg-martinbarker-test/

I am following [this](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) tutorial exactly, (except for changing the package name), but if I try to install the package with the instruction from the url:

```
pip install example-pkg-martinbarker-test
```

I get an error:

```html
# pip install example-pkg-martinbarker-test
Collecting example-pkg-martinbarker-test
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement example-pkg-martinbarker-test (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for example-pkg-martinbarker-test
```

Is it something with how I uploaded my package to twine thats causing this error?

Comment: Try looking up online what the latest version of the package is and explicitly tell `pip` that you want this particular version: `pip install <pkg>==<version>`

Comment: I tried that by running ```pip install example-pkg-martinbarker-test==0.0.1``` but I got the same error output:  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement example-pkg-martinbarker-test==0.0.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for example-pkg-martinbarker-test==0.0.1

Comment: let me try upgrading from python2.7 to 3 EDIT nvm i have both

Comment: One other thing you can try is upgrading your `pip` by running `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: ran that, didnt change the  error

Comment: If you have both Python 2.7 and 3, you can try specifying which `pip` you want to use by using `pip2` or `pip3` instead of `pip`.

Comment: _let me try upgrading from python2.7 to 3 EDIT nvm i have both_ Are you not using virtual environments?

Comment: You *really* want to specify pip via the interpreter. This is done with `python -m pip install <package>`. The reason being that you know which python you want to use, where `pip` and `pip3` can point to your system python, some other virtualenv, etc

Answer (score 1):

The install works for me when installing using Python 3, and fails using Python 2.

In this case, ensure that you are running `pip` for Python 3.  You may wish to create a virtual environment for Python 3, and install the package.

To create the virtual environment:

```
virtualenv env -p python3
```

To activate the virtual env:

```
source ./env/bin/activate
```

To check the version:

```
pip -V

pip 19.3.1 from some/path/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

To install:

```
pip install example-pkg-martinbarker-test
```

This successfully installs the package you mention.

```
Collecting example-pkg-martinbarker-test
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/34/9cb503547689819a8c98048eb7127a3538243b0d44294987dba28eeb0259/example_pkg_martinbarker_test-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: example-pkg-martinbarker-test
Successfully installed example-pkg-martinbarker-test-0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed by uninstalling pip and install pip3, then installing my package with pip3

pip install example-pkg-martinbarker-test==0.0.1

thank you